# Where to copy paste CodeIgniter 3.0.4?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm learnig Code Igniter.

I have downloaded and unzipped codeigniter 3.0.4

Where should I copy the unzipped folder "CodeIgniter-3.0.4"?

Should I copy paste the entire folder into C:\xampp\htdocs ?

Comment: Here's good reading http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/index.html I would read through all helpers and libraries.

Answer (score 1):

index.php file must be in root folder so when you open your project in localhost

```
http://localhost/mytestproject
```

you need to create a folder like this

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\mytestproject
```

and unzip everthing inside mytestproject folder